# Remove NuGet source if exists

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am trying to detect whether or not a source has been added to a configuration file. If it has been added, I would like to remove it. The tricky part is that I won't know the name of the source initially but am aware of the path.

Using `nuget sources list -configfile C:\Temp\NuGet.Config` I am able to identify the sources that have been added but this returns a string.

How can I identify if the source has been added based on the source path and extract the name of the source so that I can remove it?

Some pseudo code:

```
nuget sources add -name "example.com" -source "https://nuget.example.com/nuget" -username "example" -password "example" -storepasswordincleartext -configfile C:\Temp\NuGet.Config

if source exists with path 'https://nuget.example.com/nuget':
    remove source
```

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same question, it's a bit of a pain the dotnet CLI doesn't support removing based on a source.

I solved it this way:

```
$feedUrl = "<YourFeedUrl>"
$sources = dotnet nuget list source
$sourceName = ""
$sources -split "`n" | %{
    if($_ -match '^\s+\d+\.\s+(.*)\s+\[Enabled\]$'){
        $sourceName = $matches[1]
    } elseif ($_ -match "^\s+$feedUrl$") {
        dotnet nuget remove source $sourceName
    }
}
```

This script splits the output by lines. It then checks if the line matches the format of a source name line, in which case it saves the name. Then if it encounters a line matching the feed URL, it removes the source with the previously saved name.

That relies on `dotnet nuget list source -format detailed`, which is the default, and in my case at least outputs a list formatted this way:

```
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

Note that if the output changes in the future, or if your version of the dotnet CLI outputs something different, you may need to tweak the regex.

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not support removing source by URL and the aliases name can be different. So for this:

```
Prerequisite:the command 

Dotnet list sources gives this type of output else the grep command below will change

Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages.      [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\
```

this is the proposed shell scripting solution:

1. Use grep command to get the name using strict matching of the case and delete all source names that were found:

```
sources=$(dotnet nuget list source | grep '\[Enabled\]' | awk '{print $2}')
        
echo "$sources" | xargs -I % dotnet nuget remove source %
```

2. Add the required source:

```
Dotnet nuget add source < source-url > -n < source-name >
```